# git merge between related but different files

Tags: git, git-merge

I don't know if it makes sense to ask in context of Git but here is the thing:

There is a library I have decided to copy some classes from, modify their internals and use them in my project. These classes belong to an open source library on Github and it gets its updates from time to time.

While, I would like to modify these certain classes for own use, I would also like to get the updates from author to these classes as and when they happen.

So, for example if I have a copy of a class called `Implementation` from the library, I would be making some changes to it and then when any updates come to this class in the repo online by the author, I would like to get the merge my changes with author's changes. If there is any merge conflict, I would handle ad-hoc.

You can probably see the obvious caveat here: I don't have any clone of the lib online but only copies classes from the lib. This means, there are two `Implementation`s here - one locally on my disk(unversioned) and the other one online.

How can I merge these two implementations?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it as you want it.

I think you should make a fork of this lib, and keep your changes there (and from time to time merge with upstream).
If you find your changes useful you can ask original author to merge your changes (pull request).